# Sharepoint 2010 security validation error

Tags: 2010, security

When i try to add a link to the top nav bar, I am doing this from the cms so not from code. I get the security validation invalid error. 
http://img233.imageshack.us/img233/5761/errorcs.png

On the internet, i can find lots of reasons why this error can occur when using your own code. The thing is that i am not using any custom code.

The only thing i use is a custom master page. When i set the site to use the standard master page i do not get the error. So obviously the error is in the master page. So my question is:

Has anyone had this problem before?

Does anyone know the solution to my problem?

Any help is appreciated.

**Note : This question is still not answered**

Error:

07/29/2011 11:13:54.89                w3wp.exe (0x0EAC)                                      0x098C SharePoint Foundation                Runtime                                       tkau       Unexpected

System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: The security validation for this page is invalid. Click Back in your Web browser, refresh the page, and try your operation again.    at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequestInternalClass.AddNavigationNode(String bstrUrl, String bstrName, String bstrNodeUrl, Int32 lType, Int32 lParentId, Int32 lPreviousSiblingId, Boolean bAddToQuickLaunch, String& pbstrDateModified)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.AddNavigationNode(String bstrUrl, String bstrName, String bstrNodeUrl, Int32 lType, Int32 lParentId, Int32 lPreviousSiblingId, Boolean bAddToQuickLaunch, String& pbstrDateModified)

Answer (score 1):

Can you check to see if you've included this in your masterpage?

```
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderFormDigest" runat="server">
    <SharePoint:FormDigest runat="server"/>
</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
```

Also, Randy Drisgill has some start master pages available on [Codeplex](http://startermasterpages.codeplex.com/) that you can use.  It has all the required content place holders on it to ensure your site functions normally.

Comment: Thanks, i do have this contentplaceholder. I used the basic master page that Randy Drisgill provided. To be certain i will recheck all placeholders. Thanks for the input

Comment: i looked over every starter page and checked every content place holder and i have them all, any other suggestions?

Comment: do you see anything in the ULS logs with that correlation ID?

Comment: yes, i added it to the main question

Comment: Joel just blogged about some security validation stuff, perhaps that's what your running into, http://www.sharepointjoel.com/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=470